# optimized solution for equivalence class

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, equality

suppose there are many testcase specified by capital letter, the letters in one bracket mean these
are equal testcases.  And I want the smallest set X of letters.
   **But there is not transitive relation for the equal testcases.**
   That is, （A,B） (A,D) could not get (B，D).

so,when input is:
    (A,B) (A,C) (A,D) (E)
    obviously the output should be (A,E) not (B,C,D,E)

when input is:
     (A,B)  (A,C) (A,D)  (B,E) (C,F) (D,G)
  in this case output should be (B,C,D) not (A,E,F.G).

when input is (A,B,C) (B,D) (C,D)
   the output is either (B,C) or (A,D).

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want here?  I'm interpreting this as: you have a bunch of pairs of letters, and you want the smallest set X of letters such that every pair contains at least one letter in X.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I want the smallest set X of letters.

Comment: That's the [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) problem.  It's NP-hard.

Comment: I am trying to Google it. And can you tell me if there's global optimized solution exist.

Comment: Oh， but there may have many letters in one bracket, so it is still a NP hard?

Comment: The general problem posed is NP-hard. There will be cases where it is analytically obvious what the solution is but that doesn't change the problem class which is to do with finding algorithmic solutions.

Comment: Just a side note: the example you gave for transitivity actually isn't transitivity (assuming the pairs are ordered). (A,B) & (B,C) => (A,C) is transitivity. Also, if you say the letters denote equality, but the relation isn't transitive, that is a contradiction since equality is transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an optimization problem that can be formulated for a branch and bound solution.
See this:
http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter12.pdf